# Function that takes an array of integers as a parameter and returns the sum of odd numbers in the array

Tags: c++, arrays

I keep getting a error: "Run-Time Check Failure #3 - The variable 'x' is being used without being initialized."

I thought I initialized it with all the numbers I put in the array?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

const int MAX = 10;

int odd(int sumOdd[])
{
int sum = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < MAX; i ++)
{
    if(sumOdd[i] % 2 != 0)
    sum+=sumOdd[i]; 
}
cout << "Sum of odd integers in the array: " << sum << endl;
return sum;

}

int main()
{
int x[MAX] = {13,14,8,7,45,89,22,18,6,10};

int returnArray(x[MAX]);

cout << "Sum of odd integers in the array" << endl;

system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

Comment: `int returnArray(x[MAX]);` isn't doing wha tyou think it is.

Comment: Compile with warnings: `main.cpp: In function 'int main()':
main.cpp:23:5: warning: unused variable 'returnArray' [-Wunused-variable]
 int returnArray(x[MAX]);
main.cpp:27:16: warning: ignoring return value of 'int system(const char*)', declared with attribute warn_unused_result [-Wunused-result]
 system("pause");`

Comment: what is this? `int returnArray(x[MAX]);`

Comment: @duskast, An `int` variable that's initialized to `x[MAX]`. Or not, because it's undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int returnArray(x[MAX]); // in main
```

should be

```
returnArray(x);
```

You've already declared the function as taking an array and returning an integer, so all you need to do is call the function with the array as the parameter.

Answer (score 1):

try to change:

```
 int returnArray(x[MAX]);
```

to

```
 int sum =  returnArray(x);
 cout << "Sum of odd integers in the array" << sum << endl;
```

`returnArray` returns `sum`. You can either use a temporary variable to hold the return value and print it out or directly use the return value as follows:

```
cout << "Sum of odd integers in the array" << returnArray(x) << endl;
```

When you call a function, simply use the function name and feed it with parameters, you don't need return type anymore (`int`)  in this case. You also directly use the array name `x`, not `x[MAX]`.